# What does "There are always people who love to sweat" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

I was reading [a review on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/review/R27DQLD86U2414/ref=cm_cr_dp_title/185-1073135-0853055?ie=UTF8&ASIN=2700501322&nodeID=283155&store=books) which said the following:

> To sum up, this method works fine for me and I can recommend it wholeheartedly. But then again, there are always people who love to **sweat**...

What does *sweat* mean here?

Comment: "Sweat" also means "worry" .

Comment: The rest of the sentence is...? It could be "sweat" as in perspiration (due to exercise or a stressful situation), or worry or persevere as in "...there are always people who love to sweat it out".

Comment: @user3169 That's the end of the sentence.

Comment: @snailplane I couldn't tell because of the ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that *sweat* refers to **doing hard work**.  When you do hard work physically, you sweat, and so when you do hard work mentally, you figuratively sweat.  This is [sense three in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sweat_9):

> [intransitive] *informal* **to work hard**

Why do I interpret it this way?  Well, the review starts with this line:

> The Assimil method is a great way to build up your language skills **in an easy and relaxed manner**.

Those people who "like to sweat" are people who like to do things the hard way.  The reviewer is characterizing the Assimil method as easy and relaxed, requiring less work.

Comment: Sweat definitely means "to work hard" in this context (perhaps implying working harder than you have to because you strangely enjoy it.) One of the prior sentences in the review also gives it the needed context, despite the "..." -- "Here's a tip from my own experience: Don't go too fast, never learn more than three lessons a week. [...]To sum up, this method works fine for me and I can recommend it wholeheartedly. But then again, there are always people who love to sweat..." The author is stating an "easy route" to accomplishing a goal, but acknowledging others may want to work harder.